# neo4j failed to start on my machine

Tags: neo4j, homebrew, graph-databases

I use `brew install neo4j`, when i'm trying to start on terminal by `neo4j start`, it keep loading forever as following.

```
$ neo4j start Using additional JVM arguments:  -server
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=homebrew
-Djava.awt.headless=true Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user process [9320]... waiting for server to be ready        ...........................................................................   ...........................................................................    ...........................................................................    ......................................................................

Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

I checked some logs from neo4j already ...but it show nothing error

log messgea from `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.6/libexec/data/graph.db/messages.log`

```
2015-05-21 06:46:44.248+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.6/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore.schemastore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=64b)
2015-05-21 06:46:44.248+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.6/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=25b)
2015-05-21 06:46:44.249+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.6/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=81b)
2015-05-21 06:46:44.310+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.a.i.i.LuceneLabelScanStore]: No lucene scan store index found, this might just be first use. Preparing to rebuild.
2015-05-21 06:46:44.333+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.a.i.i.LuceneLabelScanStore]: No lucene scan store index found, this might just be first use. Preparing to rebuild.
2015-05-21 06:46:44.414+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Opened logical log [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.6/libexec/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1] version=0, lastTxId=1 (clean)
2015-05-21 06:46:44.417+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.a.i.i.LuceneLabelScanStore]: Rebuilding lucene scan store, this may take a while
2015-05-21 06:46:44.418+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.a.i.i.LuceneLabelScanStore]: Lucene scan store rebuilt (roughly -1 nodes)
2015-05-21 06:46:44.421+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.TxManager]: TM new log: tm_tx_log.1
2015-05-21 06:46:44.425+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.KernelHealth]: Kernel health set to OK
```

log message from `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.6/libexec/data/log/console.log`

```
2015-05-21 06:46:43.878+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-21 06:57:03.825+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
```

I try to use `brew` to re-install neo4j, but it doesn't help.
i'm using mac machine.
java version `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run `bin/neo4j console` to let it finish the startup.

Probably it is creating / updating an index or an internal structure that takes longer than the 120s timeout?

see

```
2015-05-21 06:46:44.417+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.a.i.i.LuceneLabelScanStore]: Rebuilding lucene scan store, this may take a while
2015-05-21 06:46:44.418+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.a.i.i.LuceneLabelScanStore]: Lucene scan store rebuilt (roughly -1 nodes)
```

Comment: it show 
`WARNING: Max 256 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Neo4j Server already running with pid 78232`